# Bash script multiplying CSV values

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk

I have a tricky CSV which should be edited with a bash.
Here how a typical line in the CSV looks like

> A;B;C;D;E
>
> 1234567;7654321;100,00;ABC;0,00

My goal is to multiply the the decimal (column C) by a factor ( e.g. 0,01 ) and put a prefix in Column B. So the CSV will look afterwards like this:

> A;B;C;D;E
>
> 1234567;abc-7654321;105,00;ABC;0,00

Comment: What you have tried here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F\; '{$2="abc-"$2;$3*=0.01}1' OFS=\; file
1234567;abc-7654321;1;ABC;0,00
```

`100,00*0,01=1` and not `105,00`

Comment: seems to be a very cleean solution, but I am not familiar with awk and don't know how to get it work exactly. =/

Comment: What does not work, we are here to help :)  `awk` is a very good tool for doing this type of changes.

Comment: okay, i tried it and it work on the first run, but has a small bug. `awk -F ";" '{print "TD" $2 ";" $3*1.1}' $inputfile > $outputfile;` is my code at the moment. unfortunalty the source decimal is in this format **1,5** so when i multiply with factor 2 it results in **2.0**

Comment: okay. a bit tricky, but I am at this stage. Anyway I need to keep the original first line. Any ideas? `#!/bin/bash
##############################
factor=1.1
sourcefile=659069_CustSpecific_20140103.txt
inputfile=659069_CustSpecific_20140103.csv
outputfile=import.csv
##############################

cp $sourcefile $inputfile;
sed -i -e 's/,/./g' $inputfile

awk -F ";" '{print "TD" $2 ";" $3*$factor}' $inputfile > $outputfile;`

Comment: `awk` does not read variable this way, change from `awk -F ";" '{print "TD" $2 ";" $3*$factor}' $inputfile > $outputfile` to `awk -F ";" '{print "TD" $2 ";" $3*f}' f="$factor" $inputfile > $outputfile`

Comment: So thanks to all contributors, finally I could put it all together to following bash code:

    `cp $sourcefile $inputfile;
    sed -i -e 's/,/./g' $inputfile
    
    awk -F ";" '{
            if ($1 =="a")
                    print "a;b";
            else
                    print "abc-" $2 ";" $3*f;
            }' f="$factor" $inputfile > $outputfile
    echo 0`

The output looks like that, maybe somebody can tell me how I can put it into x.2 decimal format?

    `a;b
    abc-1000317;6.556`

Answer (score 1):

```
export factor=0.01
prefix=abc-
IFS=';' while read a b c d e; do
  echo $a;$prefix$b;$(echo "$(echo $c|tr ',' '.')*$factor" | bc | tr '.' ',');$d;$e
done < inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: very heavy in cpu cost

Comment: well, the question requires a shell script, not a _fast_ shell script. It's kind of silly to say "I need a bash script". No you don't. You need a program.

Comment: i never say it was bad nor not working (that's way there is no -1 from my part), just that the solution is to avoid by using another way like awk that suite lot better in this context. Especially due to lot of sub process startetd at each line. But you are right, you give him a solution that work and is maybe enough for the need

Comment: Thanks Robin! I tried your script but there is a syntax error somewhere in the "do" command. If this script will work, it will be perfectly fine!

Comment: sorry, it is not a script, to make it a script you would need to add `#! /bin/bash` at the top. maybe that's the problem

Comment: i tried to combine your script with the awk syntax, but i also get a syntax error `awk: {print "TD" $2 ";" $(echo "$(echo $c|tr , .)*$factor" | bc )}
awk: ^ syntax error` here is my try: `awk -F ";" '{print "TD" $2 ";" $(echo "$(echo $c|tr ',' '.')*$factor" | bc )}' $inputfile > $outputfile;`

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to all contributors, finally I could put it all together to following bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
##############################
factor='1.1'
sourcefile=whatever.txt
inputfile=whatever.csv
outputfile=import.csv
##############################

cp $sourcefile $inputfile;
sed -i -e 's/,/./g' $inputfile

awk -F ";" '{
        if ($1 =="Cust_id")
                print "a;b";
        else
                print "abc-" $2 ";" $3*f;
        }' f="$factor" $inputfile > $outputfile
echo 0
```

The output looks like that, maybe somebody can tell me how I can put it into x.2 decimal format?

```
a;b
abc-1000317;6.556
```